# Using foldr to simplify a function (SML / NJ)

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj, fold

I have this function

```
fun exist p M = foldr( fn(x,y) => x orelse y ) false (map p M)
```

I need to write it using only the foldr function, but can only call foldr once. I'm confused on how I should handle this. Do i need to revise my anon function?

Comment: Using `foldr` to define exist(s) will result in checking all elements of a list even though you could technically stop once you find the one element that turns the predicate true. That is: `foldr` will not make your function as lazy as it could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to revise your anonymous function. You can call `p` inside it.

```
fun exist p M = foldr (fn (x, y) => y orelse (p x)) false M
```

`map` in your code transforms values to `bool` type. You can do that in anonymous function. Also, switching `x` and `y` in `orelse` will save you some machine time, since if value satisfying `p` was found, `p` won't be executed on the rest of `M`.

```
- fun exist p M = foldr (fn (x, y) => y orelse (p x)) false M;
val exist = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool
- exist (fn e => e = 1) [2,3,4];
val it = false : bool
- exist (fn e => e = 1) [2,3,4,1,2,3,4];
val it = true : bool
```

---

`foldr` takes 3 arguments

1. function to fold list. It takes tuple argument `(x, y)`, where `x` is current value from list, `y` - value list have been folded to so far.
2. Starting value. It will be passed as `y` to the first first argument function together with the last value of a list.
3. List to fold. Each value (starting last) of this list will be passed to the first argument function as `x`.

`foldr` will call folding function for every element of passed list.

Calls to folding (called it `anon` here) function for `exist (fn e => e = 1) [2,1,4];` call:

```
anon (4, false);                              // here `false` is the false passed to `foldr`; returns false
anon (1, false orelse (p 4));                 // (p 1) -> true; returns true
anon (2, (false orelse (p 4)) orelse (p 1));  // returns true becuase `true or (p 2)` is true
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused on how the whole anonymous function works in my original exist. So map will be called that will generate the list of boo-leans based on the predicate and list the user provides. Then foldr breaks down the list until it has a false value to start with. How is this value and the head of the list used in the anon function?

Comment: I guess my real confusion is after the arguments are fed into the anon function, how does everything get evaluated with the orelse statement

Comment: Hope this will be enough to explain `foldr` :-)

Comment: So even if when (p 1) gets passed in, it still has to go through and check the rest of the values?

Comment: Yes, it will go through the rest of the values, but since `orelse` executes expression on the right only when expression on the left is `false` `p` won't be called on the rest of the values.

Comment: Please accept answer if it answers your question. If it does not please, let me know why. Same applies to your other questions.

Comment: The expression can also be simplified to `fun exist p = foldr (fn (x,y) => y orelse p(x)) false` since both the `exist` function and the `foldr` function expect a list `xs` as their last argument.